# Problem with memoir and biblatex together

Tags: biblatex, memoir

For no reason I can understand, I can't compile the following using TexLive 2011:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\bibliography{mnwe-thesis}
\begin{document}

Following Serre\cite{serre_Trees}

\end{document}
```

with the `.bib` file `mnwe-thesis.bib`:

```
@Book{ serre_Trees,
address = "Berlin",
series = "Springer Monographs in Mathematics",
title = "Trees",
isbn = "3-540-44237-5",
url = "http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1954121",
publisher = "{Springer-Verlag}",
author = "{Jean-Pierre} Serre",
year = "2003",
    note = "Translated from the French original by John Stillwell, Corrected 2nd   printing of the 1980 English translation"
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
.
.
.
(./mnwe.bbl)
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 6.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 6.

! Undefined control sequence.
\biburlsetup ->\Urlmuskip 
                      =0mu plus 3mu\relax \mathchardef \UrlBigBreakPenal...
l.13 Following Serre\cite{serre_Trees}
```

I'm highly surprised since `memoir` is listed specifically as a *compatible* package in the `biblatex` docs.

**Edit:**

Changing the documentclass to `article` doesn't help. I also added `\listfiles` after `\begin{document}`. The output is here: http://pastebin.com/9dMgNzpz.

Comment: Try adding `\usepackage{url}`

Comment: I can't reproduce this, neither with `biber` nor `bibtex`. What versions of the two packages are you using and is really caused by `memoir`. What happens with one of the standard classes?

Comment: You appear to be using biblatex in a strange way. For example, you need to put `\printbibliography` before you end the document, and although I think you can use `\bibliography{...}` you should really be using `\addbibresource`. Please check the documentation for simple usage examples.

Comment: This works fine for me; can you add `\listfiles` immediately before your `\begin{document}` and post the output

Comment: Did you delete the `.bbl` auxiliary file? Perhaps there's a "bad" `.bbl` file from a previous run and this is causing the problem.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I can try this in a completely clean directory with nothing other than `mnwe.tex` and `mnwe-thesis.bib` and it still gives the error.

Comment: It seems to not be caused by `memoir` after all. Trying it with `article` gives the same problem. grepping in `biblatex.sty` suggests that `biblatex` is version 1.3.

The next thing I'll try is the `\listfiles` thing, but I'm not sure how much output to post. All of it?

Comment: 1.7 is the current version of biblatex.

Comment: OK, looking at the `grep` again, I'm using version 1.7.

Comment: Silly question; have you tried removing that space before `serre_Trees` in the `.bib` file? It probably shouldn't make a difference, and at worst should give a warning rather than an error.

Comment: The current error is from an outdated [`url` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/url). Your version is `1999/03/02 ver 1.4`, while the most recent on CTAN is `2006/04/12 ver 3.3` which defines `\Urlmuskip`.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt I've just tried it with no change, but I didn't think it could be that. If you just leave the `\cite` empty it gives the same error. It should really complain about references in that case.

Comment: @Werner That will be exactly it! Due to things beyond my control, there's a teTeX installation in parallel with the TeXlive 2011 one, and it turns out that `url.sty` is coming from the teTeX installation. Thanks for that!

I don't know if it's considered worthy of an answer, but if you want to add it as such I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: @JosephCooper --- If you can't get rid of teTeX for whatever reason, you may want to switch the order files are found by your *tex commands.  See [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=privinst) for guidance.

Comment: @jon --- thanks for that. I solved it by installing `url` in my `$HOME/texmf`, but that will require me keeping an eye out for any changes to `url`. Unlikely, but still... So your comment is very useful actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current error is from an outdated [`url` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/url). Your version is `1999/03/02 ver 1.4`, while the most recent on CTAN is `2006/04/12 ver 3.3` which defines `\Urlmuskip`.

Comment: It appears to be in `texmf-local`, so perhaps something old overriding the newer one in TeXLive 2011.