# LaTeX for typesetting a fiction book

Tags: packages, templates, document-classes, book-design

I am wondering if one can use TeX/LaTeX to typeset a full-fledged fiction book i.e. a prose, literature (not poetry) e.g. if Conan Doyle wished to write his Sherlock using TeX, what would you have in mind for him? Is TeX even right for writing a book (non-mathematical, I repeat)? I have used TeX and still am using for Math, Physics and Economics to produce articles, monograph and theses but never a fiction/literature book. Naturally, I want to have a ready-to-go template adapted for the leading world publishers style, requirements etc.

Comment: You should look into using the [memoir](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) document class. Its motto is, "Typeset fiction, non-fiction and mathematical books".

Comment: I downloaded it but the template looked, again, more suitable for scientific needs rather than typesetting a book. I was wondering if there is a package specifically for writing fiction in the same vein as disser or thesis packages are good for writing a phd paper.

Comment: One example of what you are probably looking for: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60259/6518.

Comment: For fictional books, I'd choose a author software such as Scrivener.

Comment: There are a great many parameters that no template will be able to choose for you in any meaningful sort of way. Among these parameters are the page dimensions, the dimensions of the text block, and the main font family and weight. Once you've chosen them, `memoir` will do just fine.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! [What LaTeX / LyX classes, modules and templates are available for novel writing?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114052) is a related question.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'll examine all and post If I still have questions or what I found most suitable. It just feels exhilarating to know there are so many of you who responded so quickly! Very grateful!

Comment: More questions that this one might be a duplicate of: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73618/is-there-a-class-for-writing-novels, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66902/latex-template-for-writing-a-novel. Perhaps also interesting: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135226/whats-the-chief-advantage-of-memoir-over-standard-book-for-a-novel

Comment: Also, we don't usually put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: @erreka I definitely agree that your edits changing _writing_ to _typesetting_ are semantically correct, but I’m wondering if people looking for this information might be more likely to find a question about _writing_ rather than _typesetting_.

Comment: @doncherry it seems to me that the search engine is smart enough to catch the two words "writing" and "fiction" in the same question statement, and we are educating the public stating the question in a precise way.

Comment: @erreka Well but now it says _typesetting_, and I’m not sure that novice users would necessarily think that is what they are looking for. (Let alone not-native speakers who might not even know what typesetting means.)

Comment: @doncherry I've tested the engine, and it happily finds the combinations "writing novel" and "writing fiction" in the statement and the elaboration of the questions; so I wouldn't worry about that.

Comment: The `novel` document class is now on CTAN.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in many of the comment, fiction books are usually much simpler than technical books.  When I've typeset novels, I've normally used the `book` class and tweaked it with some new sectioning commands, then called it a day.  How much redefining you need to do will depend on what kind of novel you want to write; are we talking about a longer novel, with several parts (say, *The Stand*), or a typical sci-fi paperback (say, *Snow Crash*)?  Named chapters, or merely numbered?  (I typeset one where each chapter was a different *date*, so the headings here were a bit more complicated.)  In the simplest case, you can do something like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\def\newchap{%
    \stepcounter{chapter}%
    \renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Chapter \thechapter}%
    \vskip3em plus1em minus1em%
    \hbox to\linewidth{%
        \hfil%
        \Huge\scshape Chapter \thechapter%
        \hfil%
    }%
    \penalty10000\vskip3em plus1em minus1em%
    \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading%
}%
\def\newsect{%
    \vskip2em plus0.5em minus0.5em%
    \hbox to\linewidth{\hfil*\quad\quad*\quad\quad*\hfil}%
    \penalty10000\vskip2em plus0.5em minus0.5em%
    \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading%
}
\makeatother%
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newchap
\lipsum[1]

\newchap
\lipsum[2-3]
\newsect
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

This will give you the fiction-looking following (plus a not-very-fictiony TOC at the top, just to show that it works):

[image: Spread of novel-like typsetting.]

The problem with writing a "fiction" class is that, although the typesetting is typically much simpler than (say) an algebra textbook, the variation in fiction typesetting is huge.  For one thing, when we say "fiction," do we mean short-stories, novellas, novels, trilogies?  Do we want named chapters or only numbered?  Both?  What kind of section separators do we want?  And so forth.  At that point, we might as well just have a `book` or `memoir` class and trim it down.

As for publishers, I think one of the commenters already mentioned it:  they just want very basic double-spaced type without much formatting.  There are already classes to give this very basic appearance; e.g., `manuscript` (though that might get even more bare-bones than a publisher wants).

I hope this helps at least a little.

Comment: I'm glad. If it was helpful, or even answered your question, would you consider upvoting (the up arrow by the top of the question) or accepting (the checkmark just below it) it? That's the preferred way to say thanks or to affirm an answer's usefulness in our community.

Comment: I have around 1000 pages written on MS Word. Most body of work is arranged in Parts (5 to 7 parts), which consist of Chapters (I need both named and numbered chapters). I also have a large collection of manuscripts on separate word files, which I also want to incorporate, preferably into a single .tex file or package. When I wrote my last dissertation I used .disser class, broke my chapters into separate .tex files and defined chapters and sections using \chapter{} and \section{} with labels also using hyperlinks. I love TeX and I basically want to gather my work into a unified TeX document as

Comment: as having loads of Word documents makes it harder to edit my work (it is largely finished and I need to “bind it up” now). I am looking for something of this sort to satisfy the following:

1) allow easy navigation e.g. clickable TOC and other possible useful features
2) look maximally as a “venerable book”
3) allow easily change the sizes, fonts and other such technical issues as I haven’t yet approached a publisher and I want to “clean it up” and “bind it” into a really fancy book first

Comment: 4) I would like the book show the name of each chapter above the relevant page + general numeration
5) Each chapter will have an epigraph tiled up in the right upper corner in form of a small verse (with stanzas) so I’d also want some style to enable this

Comment: `book` (with packages) or `memoir` (without) will do all of that.  It will be much easier than rolling your own styles.

Comment: `scrbook` (Koma-Script ‘book’ class) might also be a viable alternative.